# MySQL - Modify query depending on field value

Tags: mysql

I want the following query to change depending on the value of `specimen.snop_axis`, which can be 'M' or 'F':

```
SELECT *
FROM specimen,
     topography_index,
     morphology,
     FUNCTION
WHERE SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code
  AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
  AND specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
```

So that if specimen.snop_axis == M then add

`AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code`

else if specimen.snop_axis == F then add

`AND functions.function_code = specimen.snop_code`

**UPDATE**

I have changed the query as suggested to:

```
SELECT * FROM specimen, topography_index, morphology, functions 
WHERE 
SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code 
AND 
IF(specimen.snop_axis == 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.function_code = specimen.snop_code) 
AND 
specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.function_code' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT *
FROM specimen,
     topography_index,
     morphology,
     FUNCTION
WHERE SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code
  AND specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
  AND if(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.function_code = specimen.snop_code);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error...see changed query in OP

Comment: Sorry, it was because of the ==, in mysql it is = to check equality.

Comment: Mmm...that should work, but it's returning 2292 records of the same specimen.snop_code...there are 2292 records in the table morphology...

Comment: You are joining 4 tables, and you are doing * which means it will returns all the columns from all 4 tables. specify which column you need and also relation ship between these tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use case statement like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM specimen, topography_index, morphology, function WHERE SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code 
AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code 
AND specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
AND CASE WHEN specimen.snop_axis = M THEN morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
ELSE function.function_code = specimen.snop_code END;
```

This might can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make them as conditional clauses using the logical operations `AND` and `OR`, as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM specimen,
     topography_index,
     morphology,
     FUNCTION
WHERE SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code
  AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
  AND specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
  AND (
    (specimen.snop_axis = 'M' AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code)
    OR 
    (specimen.snop_axis = 'F' AND functions.function_code = specimen.snop_code)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM specimen,
     topography_index,
     morphology,
     FUNCTION
WHERE SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code
AND morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code
AND specimen.topography_index = '_ORGAN_'
AND (if(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', 
     morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, 
     functions.function_code = specimen.snop_code) 
OR if(specimen.snop_axis = 'F',functions.function_code = specimen.snop_code));
```